# ControlClicking on a window hidden by 'winHide'?

Tags: autohotkey

This is something that AutoIt can apparently do, [Send ControlClick to Hidden Window?](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/45045-send-controlclick-to-hidden-window/).
My tests with AHK tells me its not possible

```
controlClick, 100,10, ahk_exe foobar2000.exe,,,, NA
```

The above clicks on top left of foobars window (Win32 UI), without activating the window. The following is the same but meant to click on Foobar while it is hidden but upon showing the window, it is evident the button was not clicked:

```
DetectHiddenWindows, on
WinHide, ahk_exe foobar2000.exe
sleep, 500
controlClick, 100,10, ahk_exe foobar2000.exe,,,, NA
sleep, 500
winShow, ahk_exe foobar2000.exe
```

Its my understanding that both AutoIt and AutoHotkey are using the same underlying windows facilities, so I dont understand discrepancy.

Can anyone confirm if they have ever managed to get `controlClick` to work on hidden windows?

Comment: [That code](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/45045-send-controlclick-to-hidden-window/)  from 2007 only works on Windows XP. Windows 7 was released on July 22, 2009.

Comment: @Relax, hehe I missed that part, fair enough